# How to check the pdf file is editable or not(protected) in java

Tags: java, pdf, adobe, itext, pdfbox

Given a `pdf` file, is it possible to determine if that file is editable or not in Java? `PDDocument.getCurrentAccessPermission().isReadOnly()` does not work.

Comment: When you say 'not working', what do you mean? What result do you get by running that function?

Comment: Yes, it would have been better to include the code that isn't working. And explain why itext was put into the tag list, e.g. "what would be the code for itext"?

Comment: Have you decided whether you want an answer for itext too? If you don't want an answer for itext, then remove the itext tag. (You can edit) If you do want an answer for itext too, then mention what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

In the 1.8 versions, when using the "old" parser, you need to call `openProtection()` first, because such files are "encrypted" with the empty password:

```
if (doc.isEncrypted()
{
    doc.openProtection(new StandardDecryptionMaterial(""));
}
```

and then you can call

```
doc.getCurrentAccessPermission().isReadOnly()
```

or any other method from the `AccessPermission` class.

Alternatively, load your PDF with the "new" non-sequential parser:

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(new File(...), null);
```

and then `doc.getCurrentAccessPermission().isReadOnly()` can also be called.

Comment: Need to check both password protectd pdf  and protected pdf file and to pull the seperate  error message for both 
but the above code is working fine for protected file but not for password protected file.
Getting the below error  Caused by: org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.CryptographyException: 
Error: The supplied password does not match either the owner or user password in the document.
I need to check the password is null or not for pdf file.Please let me know.how to differ.

Comment: Here is the code:                                                     if(document.isEncrypted())
{                                                                                       
     String  a = "PASSWORD_PROTECTED";  
     doc.openProtection(new StandardDecryptionMaterial(""));
     if(!document.getCurrentAccessPermission().canModify()) 
     {           
        String     a = "PROTECTED";                
     }  
}

Comment: @YashwanthKothapa That isn't what your question was about. But it is easy: if you get a crypto exception despite opening with the empty password, then obviously the file is password protected.